# RSqlite create table from dataframe, specify primary unique key

Tags: r, database, sqlite

I am using RSqlite::dbWriteTable to periodically save chunks of data in a sqlite database. This method has the advantage that if the table does not exist yet, it creates it the first time and append data the subsequent times.

This method, although, doesn't let you specify a primary key and therefore it's not safe against duplicated records.

Is there a way to solve this or another method as flexible ad dbWriteTable that is duplicates safe?

Thanks